# Is there any easy way to save cv::mat as npy file in C++?

Tags: c++, numpy, opencv

I'm modifying the output of one system to match the input of another system. The first system was written in C++ and second system was written in python. The second system requires npy file as input, so I have to save cv:Mat as npy file in the first system. But when I did some investigation on Internet, I found I may have to use boost::python to do so. Is there any easy way to save cv:mat to npy file, because I don't want to install python on my machine.

Comment: I found [xtensor](https://xtensor.readthedocs.io/en/latest/file_loading.html#loading-npy-data-into-xtensor) pretty useful, or something like [libnpy](https://github.com/llohse/libnpy)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can interface with numpy's C bindings in a relatively straight forward way. You'll want to do read the rather well-written numpy documentation on "extending numpy" with native code.

If course, to write C++ code that uses numpy code to write bumpy files, to will need to install numpy development headers. Which will probably lead to the installation of numpy and thus python anyways.

However, honestly, `numpy.fromfile` can load raw data files, containing nothing but the numbers as they were in the memory of your openCV C++ program just fine. So, if you don't need to transport any complicated structure between these program parts, but just arrays of numbers, that's easier.

Another option is to save hdf5; numpy can read that structured file format, and there's libraries for C and C++ to write it.

The most common way is to just use your c++ code as a library, and build a bit of wrapper, so you can call your C++ code from python with numpy data types, and the wrapping paper magically does the conversion of numpy arrays to C++ types and back. I think these days, pybind11 is the most popular wrapper, and it does wrap to and from numpy ndarray rather well.

Comment: Thank you very much. We decided to handle it one python side.